# Printing locations of non-zero elements of an array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array `y`. I am identifying all nonzero elements with `np.nonzero()`.

But, I want to print the output in a way as shown in the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

y=np.array([[ 0.0, -1.3e-08, 0.0 ],
            [-1.3e-08,  0.0, 1.4e-9],
            [0.0, 2.3e-7, 1.9e-6]])

Result=np.nonzero(y)
print(Result)
```

The current output is:

```
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64), array([1, 0, 2, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

The expected output is:

```
array([[0,1],[1,0],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]])
```

Comment: you didn't read the np.nonzero` docs carefully enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `np.stack`

```
import numpy as np

y=np.array([[ 0.0, -1.3e-08, 0.0 ],
            [-1.3e-08,  0.0, 1.4e-9],
            [0.0, 2.3e-7, 1.9e-6]])

Result=np.nonzero(y)
np.stack(Result, axis = -1)
```

Output

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Comment: `np.argwhere` uses `np.transpose(result)` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

y=np.array([[ 0.0, -1.3e-08, 0.0 ],
            [-1.3e-08,  0.0, 1.4e-9],
            [0.0, 2.3e-7, 1.9e-6]])

Result=np.nonzero(y)

print(np.array([[x,y] for x,y in zip(Result[0],Result[1])]))
```